# Sorting lines numerically by field in AWK

Tags: awk

I have a text file containing these characters, where my delimiter/separator is `##@##`:

```
Steve##@##Jobs##@##Apple Inc.##@##32421213
Bill##@##Gates##@##Microsoft Corp.##@##234213
Steve##@##Wozniak##@##Apple Inc.##@##12343
Tim##@##Cook##@##Apple Inc.##@##323345223
```

Now I want them to be sorted numerically & ascending by the third field. I read that it would be possible to use the bash command `sort`, which unfortunately only supports a single character as delimiter.

Eventually the sorted file should exactly look like this one:

```
Steve##@##Wozniak##@##Apple Inc.##@##12343
Bill##@##Gates##@##Microsoft Corp.##@##234213
Steve##@##Jobs##@##Apple Inc.##@##32421213
Tim##@##Cook##@##Apple Inc.##@##323345223
```

Is there a fix for sort or can I do this using awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (hackish) idea. Use `awk` to add the numeric field to the beginning of each line, so that we can sort it with `sort` and then use `sed` to get rid of the stuff that we added in the first step. Something like that:

```
awk -vFS='##@##' '{print $4 "|" $0}' input | sort -n | sed -e 's/^[^|]*|//'
```

Comment: That is the standard approach but use `\t` instead of `|` as the separator since that's the default `sort` delimiter and so you can tell sort to only use the first field (as is YMMV with the order of `|` vs other characters) and also so you can just use cut with it's default separator afterwards: `awk -F'##@##' -v OFS='\t' '{print $4, $0}' input | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2-`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `perl`, no need of other commands

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Steve##@##Jobs##@##Apple Inc.##@##32421213
Bill##@##Gates##@##Microsoft Corp.##@##234213
abc##@##xyz##@##123 Corp.##@##234213
Steve##@##Wozniak##@##Apple Inc.##@##12343
Tim##@##Cook##@##Apple Inc.##@##323345223

$ perl -ne '($k)=/(\d+)$/; $h{$k} .= $_; END{foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %h){print $h{$_}}}' ip.txt 
Steve##@##Wozniak##@##Apple Inc.##@##12343
Bill##@##Gates##@##Microsoft Corp.##@##234213
abc##@##xyz##@##123 Corp.##@##234213
Steve##@##Jobs##@##Apple Inc.##@##32421213
Tim##@##Cook##@##Apple Inc.##@##323345223
```

- The number at end of line is used as a key
- Input line is appended to hash variable based on key, that way multiple lines with same key is also handled
- After all lines are processed, the keys are sorted numerically and corresponding values are printed out

Answer (score 0):

Because **sort**(1) accepts only a single-character delimiter, you want to convert your separator string into something sort recognizes, but is not a value that appears in your data.  Your best choice is something that *can't* appear in the data: a non-printable character.  A reasonable candidate is the ASCII field separator, octal 034.  Then of course you have to restore your separator after sorting.

If you use bash, you have straightforward access to characters by octal value, else your shell may vary.  Then **sed** makes it a snap:

```
$ s=$'\034'
$ sed "s/##@##/$s/g" dat | sort -t $s -k4 -n | sed "s/$s/##@##/g"

Steve##@##Wozniak##@##Apple Inc.##@##12343
Bill##@##Gates##@##Microsoft Corp.##@##234213
Steve##@##Jobs##@##Apple Inc.##@##32421213
Tim##@##Cook##@##Apple Inc.##@##323345223
```